# How to set template of boolean field if value is 0 in node display

Tags: 7, entities

I have a custom template file for a boolean field with a checkbox within a content type. The checkbox values are **ON** for true and **OFF** for false. It works perfectly if the checkbox is checked. But if the checkbox is not checked the template will be ignored and the value **OFF** will be rendered plain into the node. 
How to get it to render the output with template or simply remove the output at all if checkbox is not checked?

Comment: Can you add the code which displays the field? You should be able to just check for a "0" value...

Comment: its a boolean field with a checkbox without any additional code. the only thing i've changed are the values. the fields name is **field_in_slideshow** and the name of the file is **field--field-in-slideshow--projects.tpl.php**. the content of this file ist `<?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?><div class"in_slideshow"><?php print render($item); ?></div><?php endforeach; ?>`.

Comment: I use to add the same field when using a slideshow. I've since found its more useful to use the built-in flag "promote to front page". Would that get around your problem?

Comment: Ya, i could use that. I've already decided to put it into a view block and load the images from there.